# vector changes to matrix at computation

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

This is probably a rookie mistake that I'm missing somewhere but I can't for the life of me find anything related to my problem on the web.

I have a vector `b1` of size `5 by 1`, and i have another vector `dsdb1` which is also `5 by 1`.

When I write `b1 += tau*dsdb1` I get the error "non-broadcastable output operand with shape (5,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (5,5)"

Now, no one of these is a matrix. I even deleted this line and instead printed both sizes for b1 and dsdb1. For b1 it printed (5,1) and for dsdb1 it printed (5,). tau is just a scalar.

Why is it changing dsdb1 to a 5 by 5 matrix when computing?

Comment: How is the vector defined? What object is it? Part of numpy?

Comment: both are numpy vectors. b1 is random initially. dsdb1 is computed via a rather lengthy process, but ends with numpy.sum, so yes, i believe both are numpy vectors

Comment: can you print these out with their types ?

Comment: `dsdb1 it printed (5,)` ?

Comment: both are numpy.ndarray, just checked. and b1 is size (5,1), and dsdb1 is size (5,). Whatever that means. yes. it printed (5,).

Comment: there you go, it should be `(5,1)` instead of `(5,)` . double check how you are creating your dsdb1

Comment: dsdb1 is computed correctly. as in the values are correct. it is computed via dsdb1 = np.sum(dw2_mul_h,axis = 1) where dw2_mul_h is (5,60000). the np.sum returns a (5,) vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by using a temp variable, setting it to correct size, and iterating over dsdb1. i still don't know what caused the bug.